# Securing a HTML form, before it sends data to a mysqli database

Tags: php, mysqli, forms

I want to know if there is any better, or more ways/solutions to secure a form that is open to the public.

I want to make it as secure as possible.

```
<?php
ob_start();

$sub_firstname = trim($_POST["firstname"]);
$sub_lastname = trim($_POST["lastname"]);
$sub_email = trim($_POST["email"]);
$sub_youtube_v = trim($_POST["youtube-v"]);
$sub_youtube_c = trim($_POST["youtube-c"]);
$sub_portfoliolink = trim($_POST["portfolio-link"]);
$sub_picturelink = trim($_POST["picture-link"]);

include('../dbconnect.php');

if (empty($sub_firstname) || empty($sub_lastname ) || empty($sub_email) || empty($sub_youtube_v)
    || empty($sub_youtube_c) || empty($sub_portfoliolink) || empty($sub_picturelink)) {
    header ("Location: ../index.php?appform=empty");
    exit;
}

$sub_firstname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($sub_firstname);
$sub_lastname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($sub_lastname);
$sub_email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($sub_email);
$sub_youtube_v = $mysqli->real_escape_string($sub_youtube_v);
$sub_youtube_c = $mysqli->real_escape_string($sub_youtube_c);
$sub_portfoliolink = $mysqli->real_escape_string($sub_portfoliolink);
$sub_picturelink = $mysqli->real_escape_string($sub_picturelink);

htmlspecialchars($sub_firstname);
htmlspecialchars($sub_lastname);
htmlspecialchars($sub_email);
htmlspecialchars($sub_youtube_v);
htmlspecialchars($sub_youtube_c);
htmlspecialchars($sub_portfoliolink);
htmlspecialchars($sub_picturelink);

if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ********* (firstname, lastname, email, youtube_v, youtube_c, portfolio_link, picture_link) VALUES('$sub_firstname', '$sub_lastname', '$sub_email', '$sub_youtube_v', '$sub_youtube_c', '$sub_portfoliolink', '$sub_picturelink')")) {
 echo "Insert failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
 die();
}else{
header("Location: ../index.php?appform=success");
exit;
ob_flush();
}
?>
```

Comment: Redirecting away if at least one of the fields was left empty is bad UX – then the user will have to enter all other values they already input again. Instead you should display the form again, with all fields that the user already input values for pre-filled (and probably specific error messages as to what’s missing). And using `htmlspecialchars` on your data before inserting it into the database is just plain wrong – you do that when you _output_ the data, not when you’re storing it. And the use of output buffering seems superfluous here.

Comment: @CBroe i removed the htmlspecialchars, i have no idea how to do what you just told me. :( what is output buffering?

Answer (score 0):

One main thing you might be looking for is a [CSLF token](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_CSRF_Guard). This is essentially a randomly generated token on your form that is submitted as a hidden input, which will then be authenticated in your form processor. This will help address Cross Site Forgery Attacks.

You're essentially checking to make sure that the form is coming from you, and not being submitted by an outside resource.

Comment: I do not understand the risks. :(

Comment: How about doing something like this? <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

Comment: The risk is that I could make my own form on my own site that submits to your site. Even if it were sanitized on your end, you still wouldn't want to get my garbage into your database. For it to work, you need to have the `CSLF token` on your form, not just the processor.

Comment: so it would be best to use a CSLF token?

Comment: It would make it more secure for defending Cross Site forgery attempts. Here is a fairly good list of ways in which a form could be attacked http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/2.html

Answer (score 0):

**Use html chars:**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(/*Page name and extension here with root*/);?>">
```

**Use form form keys if you want:**
Reference(sorry):

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/secure-your-forms-with-form-keys--net-4753

**Use SSL**
Just google it and get one SSl certificate for free or pay for one.

**Use CSRF Protection**
Reference(sorry):

http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries

Any more just comment.